# Can't render form fields on profile page so that I can update profile image

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Form code:

```
class PFPform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['profile_pic' , 'username']
```

I added username to check/debug

View code:

```
def signed_in_view(request):
form = PFPform()
return render(request, "hobbies/signed_in.html", {
    "title": "Signed In Page",
    "h1": "Signed In Page",
})
```

Where form is called on html template.

```
  <form method = "POST" action ="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {%csrf_token%}
          {{ form }}
          <input class = "btn btn-primary" type = "submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: Please provide short description of your question for others to understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `"form": form` in you views render section